# Cannot remove article info

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles

I've created an article, and in its options I've set to hide the article info (Publish date, Hits, and so on). When I show the article on the site, I can see these data that are not hidden. I've already cleared the cache, and I've noticed that if I change the position of article info (above, below, split) these changes are set correctly.

How can I hide the article info?

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are created a menu item for the article (Single Article menu item) then the article options are overriden by the menu options. You should hide those article infos (Publish date, Hits, and so on) from the menu option, not the article option.

Comment: Thanks that was the problem. I've set the menu in order to use the article settings.